# Open link for installation on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have an Android application. I can add posts to timeline using it. Every such post is signed with message "via ЖАЛОБАнк" below. When I click to this link, open page for this app.
How make opening Google Play or other page in browser for installation this app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/app-link-requests/ read this

Comment: Thanks to every one! But I understand you think I open from Adnroid. And I said about desktop browser.
And I should say that no method is for showing Play Google in Facebook app page. Because every page in Google Play (I mean web version) has in header special string for blocking showing in Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an intent to open a link when the user clicks on it. For instance, you can do this `onClick()`

```
Intent fb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
fb.setData(Uri.parse("http://facebook.com"));
startActivity(fb);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but this should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri
                    .parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana"));
startActivity(intent);
```